# How to add specialized words to a trained `bert-base-uncased` embedding using the text R package for PCA mapping?

Tags: r, bert-language-model, r-text

I am using the trained `bert-base-uncased` model with the `text` R package for embedding of software help requests and produce a 2d word plot. Words that are split into tokens do not get a mapping. The following small example takes a few seconds after installing the required pieces:

```
# devtools::install_github("oscarkjell/text")
# library(text)
# textrpp_install()
# textrpp_initialize(save_profile = TRUE)

tx = c("mpirun not recognized in Slurm scripts",  "Python package ingress request",
  "Account locked out",  "New Account Creation",  "Login problems",
  "Ingress for GitHub repositories",  "Saving SQL Tables", 
  "install OpenMPI", "install R package pbdMPI")

we = textEmbed(texts = tx, model = 'bert-base-uncased', layers = 11:12,
               aggregation_from_tokens_to_word_types = "mean")
pca = textPCA(words = c("R MPI mpirun Slurm SQL Python account login"),
              word_types_embeddings = we$word_types$texts)
pca
as.vector(we$word_types$texts$words)
```

The commented lines need to be run only once to install some components.

The output from the last two lines is

```
> pca
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  words       n Dim_PC1 Dim_PC2
  <chr>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 account     1  -29.3    -16.0
2 login       1   NA       NA  
3 mpi         1   NA       NA  
4 mpirun      1   NA       NA  
5 python      1    9.92    27.0
6 r           1   28.4    -22.4
7 slurm       1   NA       NA  
8 sql         1   -8.98    11.4
> as.vector(we$word_types$texts$words)
 [1] "##b"        "##dm"       "##es"       "##i"        "##in"       "##ir"      
 [7] "##m"        "##mp"       "##osi"      "##pi"       "##ress"     "##th"      
[13] "##tori"     "##ub"       "##un"       "##ur"       "[CLS]"      "[SEP]"     
[19] "account"    "creation"   "for"        "gi"         "in"         "ing"       
[25] "install"    "locked"     "log"        "mp"         "new"        "not"       
[31] "open"       "out"        "p"          "package"    "problems"   "python"    
[37] "r"          "recognized" "rep"        "request"    "saving"     "scripts"   
[43] "sl"         "sql"        "tables"    
>
```

The `tibble` gives the 2d PCA mapping of the requested words. Since some words are whole in the `bert-base-uncased` model, such as "account" "r" "python" "sql", they receive a mapping. But other words, such as "mpi", are split as "mp" "##i" and get an `NA`.

How can the split words be added to the mapping? The `aggregation_from_tokens_to_word_types` option in `textEmbed()` does not seem to go far enough and leaves specialized words as split tokens.

Comment: good question -- this has not been implemented, but is something on the implementation list.

Comment: Thanks for validating my question! So for a word like "mpi" is it correct to aggregate the mapping for "mp" and "##i"?

Comment: yes that would be my appraoch.